# Does carbon dioxide absorb visible light to any degree?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, spectroscopy, absorption

Does carbon dioxide absorb visible light to any degree?
I found this: https://www.dinosaurtheory.com/thick_atmosphere.html and I wondered whether several hundred atmospheres worth of CO2 really would allow light to reach the surface.
So is there anywhere that gives info on the degree to which CO2 absorbs visible light?

Comment: At hundreds of atmospheres at normal Earth temperatures, CO2 will be either a liquid or a solid. The critical point is 31C and 73 bar. Pure CO2 has no optical transitions in the visible, so any effects (in the gas phase) would be scattering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, visible light absorption would correspond to some electronic excitation in an atom or molecule. So, to answer your question we just need to find experimental data on the absorption spectrum of carbon dioxide in the visible region. The image below shows this, and you can see that carbon dioxde shows essentially **no** absorption in the visible range. The image is taken from [this](https://www.randombio.com/co2.html) reference.

[image: Absorption spectra]

Comment: Yes but are atmosphere has a few tenths of a millibar worth of CO2, I'm talking dozens of bars of CO2.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, almost anything and everything absorbs and/or refracts/reflects light. If you would have several hundred atmospheres, some light would still be visible, but it would be really dim.

Comment: Does CO2 actually absorb visible light? What mechanism do you propose for an absorption feature in CO2?